# Obtener las variables de una lista en python

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando una lista de nombre `cnt` que tiene esta forma,

```
[[[1555 1379]]
 [[1554 1380]]
     ...
 [[1549 1380]]]
```

El primer valor de cada fila es la coordenada X y el segundo la coordenada Y. Mi idea es obtener el valor máximo y mínimo de cada eje.

Yo lo estoy intentando así, pero me estoy equivocando (creo) en el índice.

```
x0, x1 = np.min(cnt[:, 0]), np.max(cnt[:, 0])
y0, y1 = np.min(cnt[:, 1]), np.max(cnt[:, 1])
```

También he probado así pero no me dan bien.

```
x0, x1 = np.min(cnt[0]), np.max(cnt[0])
y0, y1 = np.min(cnt[1]), np.max(cnt[1])
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias.

Comment: No se si entiendo bien la pregunta. Quieres saber cual de los dos valores de cada fila es más grande, si el eje X o el Y y viceversa?

Comment: No, quiero saber el valor max y min para cada columna. :)

Comment: En este ejemplo sería, x0 =1549, x1=1555, y0=1379, y1=1380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por el `print` que muestras y cómo indizas, `cnt` no es una lista (`list`) es un array de NumPy tridimensional. En tal caso usa el argumento `axis` de `numpy.min` y `numpy.max`:

```
import numpy as np


cnt = np.array([[[1555, 1379]],
                [[1554, 1380]],
                [[1549, 1380]]])

x0, y0 = cnt.min(axis=0)[0]
x1, y1 = cnt.max(axis=0)[0]
```

> ```
> >>> x0, x1
> (1549, 1555)
> >>> y0, y1
> (1379, 1380)
> ```

En cuanto a tu intento, el problema es que con `cnt[:, 0]` seleccionas todas las filas (`:`) y de ellas la primera columna (`0`), la única que tiene el array, `cnt[:, 1]` es inválido por tanto. Deberías ser en todo caso:

```
x0, x1 = np.min(cnt[:,:,0]), np.max(cnt[:,:,0])
y0, y1 = np.min(cnt[:,:,1]), np.max(cnt[:,:,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Relacionado [Finding max value in the second column of a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800419/finding-max-value-in-the-second-column-of-a-nested-list)

Prueba esto:

```
x_min = min(tu_matriz, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]
x_max = max(tu_matriz, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]

y_min = min(tu_matriz, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
y_max = max(tu_matriz, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
```

## Cómo funciona?

El módulo `min y max` tiene un argumento opcional `key` que ejecuta una función por cada elemento de la lista, y como tienes una lista dentro de una lista, lo que hace con el modulo `lambda` es declarar en la misma linea (por comodidad) una función que en este caso en particular devuelve el elemento [n] de tu lista de ejes que hay dentro de tu matriz y la pasa a `min y max` respectivamente. `min y max` te devuelve el elemento de la lista que coincida con el máximo y el mínimo así que los "[0] y [1]" del final de cada linea especifica que quieres el primer y segundo valor de cada eje.

Ejemplo:

```
In [1]: matrix = [[10,20],[25,50],[100,3]]                                                                                                                 

In [2]: x_min = min(matrix, key=lambda x: x[0])                                                                                                         

In [3]: x_min                                                                                                                                              
Out[3]: [10, 20]  

In [4]: x_max = max(matrix, key=lambda x: x[0])                                                                                                         

In [5]: x_max                                                                                                                                              
Out[5]: [100, 3] 

In [6]: x_min = min(matrix, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]                                                                                              

In [7]: x_min                                                                                                                                              
Out[7]: 10

In [8]: x_max = max(matrix, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]                                                                                             

In [9]: x_max                                                                                                                                              
Out[9]: 100
```

Comment: Disculpa, pero me sale este error al ejecutar tu código. `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Mi matriz se llama `cnt`

Comment: Y si los espacios los he puesto son querer, es puramente visual. Creo mi problema viene al ser 3 corchetes lo que contiene los datos.

Comment: Es posible que con los tres corchetes hayas creado una lista de lista de listas

Comment: Si  te sigue dando el error quizás tengamos que ver un poco más del código o explicar de donde viene esa lista por si hubiera una manera más optimizada de escribirla

Comment: Como comento en mi respuesta `cnt` no es una lista, es un array de NumPy de **tres dimensiones**. La forma que planteas en esta respuesta es aplicable también, pero se debe usar un nivel más de indizado, para **x**:  `x_min = min(cnt, key=lambda x: x[0][0])[0][0]` , para **y**:  `y_min = min(cnt, key=lambda x: x[0][1])[0][1]`.  Un saludo.